# What is TortoiseHg Overlay Icon Server

Tags: tortoisehg

I just install TortoiseHg, to act as Mercurial client tool.

However, in my Vista, whenever I start, there is a `TortoiseHg Overlay Icon Server` at my notification bar.

Is quite annoying. What is the purpose of that? Can I disable it?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The notification icon is part of a service* which gives us those handy [icons](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-1) on the corner of version-controlled files/folders. (The little icons demonstrate whether the file is "up-to-date", modified, etc.)

---

If you want to get rid of the icon:

1. Right-click on **Desktop**
2. Click on **TortoiseHg->Explorer Extension Settings**
3. Click on **Icons**
4. Uncheck **Show Icon** under **Taskbar**

---

[image]

---

My current setup is that I've disabled TortoiseHgOverlayServer from starting up with Windows through msconfig's Startup tab. (To run msconfig, press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd>, and type in `msconfig`.)

Then, when I want my icons to update, I right click on my project folder, and click on `TortoiseHg->Update Icons`. This starts TortoiseHgOverlayServer manually, and it'll only be there until you log off Windows.

---

*It's not really a Windows service, but it acts kinda like one, so...

Comment: AND a waaaaaaaaaay better answer!! You actually explain what it is for!

Answer (score 18):

It is the service, which modifies the icon in the explorer which showes when files are under version control and if they are changed. Let it do its work.

Comment: This is the only answer that bothers to answer the question of what it is.

Comment: Exactly. Also the tray icon TURNS GREEN when the process actually performs file-system monitoring and updates the overlay icons for files/folders.